# Crumb with Golang's net/http header

Tags: curl, jenkins, go, csrf, csrf-protection

I was adding crumb CSRF protection support as part of the Golang code I wrote for interacting with Jenkins RESTful API (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

struct:

```
type Crumb struct {
  Crumb               string      `json:"crumb"`
  CrumbRequestField   string      `json:"crumbRequestField"`
}
```

code

```
  ...
  crb := Crumb{}
  // did some work to jsonify the crumb to Golang struct
  // https://jenkins.mydomain.com/crumbIssuer/api/json
  ...


  if (crb.Crumb != "" && crb.CrumbRequestField != "" ) {
    req.Header.Set(crb.CrumbRequestField, crb.Crumb)
  }

  req.SetBasicAuth(jenkins.auth.Username, jenkins.auth.ApiToken)

  // i think the issue is related to DefaultClient, but not sure
  return http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

But with Golang implementation above keep getting 403, but the same thing works fine with cURL call.

```
&{403 No valid crumb was included in the request 403 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Server:[nginx] Date:[Thu, 31 Jul 2014 05:58:52 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1] Connection:[keep-alive] Cache-Control:[must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store]] 0xc20800ff80 -1 [chunked] false map[] 0xc2082ba270 0xc208005da0}
```

cURL log:

```
> POST /computer/node1/toggleOffline HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic <key>
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: jenkins.mydomain.com
> Accept: */*
> .crumb: 0d6401898751f250ff1f95b5bf9589db
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here. I found my issue and it has nothing related to Golang's net/http lib. The Jenkins crumb GET request required that you need to provide basic auth to obtain properly crumb.